# Creating a line graph with arbitrary X axis sample positions on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot, jbchartview

I need to create a line graph on iOS. The graph is a time series, with time along the X axis and a percentage value along the Y axis. I need to be able to set both the X and Y position of each sample, because the samples are not taken at a regular interval (ie. the X axis positions are arbitrary). I do not want to normalise the data to a fixed interval, because that will cause rounding and so on. I have tried Core Plot and JBChartView, but I cannot find any way to set the X positions in either of these libraries.

1. Is there any way to set the X axis position of each sample in these libraries? I've looked through all the protocols, but it's possible I've missed something.
2. If it is not possible to set the X axis position in either of those libraries, can you recommend a graphing library that has this functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Core Plot](https://github.com/core-plot) can absolutely do this. The scatterplot pulls data from its datasource independently for the x- and y-values. Most of the included examples just use the data index for the x-value, but that choice was only to make the examples easier to follow. The x-values can be anything. The examples that use a date scale on the x-axis are one demonstration of this feature. The plot values do not need to be evenly spaced; the data is a series of x-y pairs.

Comment: Thanks for your input! An explanation on how to do it would have helped, but your response prompted me to dig deeper and realise the data source method just gets called twice (once for X and once for Y).

Answer (score 2):

Look at these Libraries

https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph

https://github.com/freshking/DynamicGraphView

Hopefully this will help